# ToString back again to color (Visual basic 2008)

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, visual-studio

My problem is that I'm trying to parse a String to a System.Drawing.Color. Im trying to set up a simple notepad, here's part of my code:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As       System.EventArgs) Handles Colorfuente2.Click
    Try
        Dim cdlg As New ColorDialog
        cdlg.ShowDialog()
        cdlg.FullOpen = True
        cdlg.AnyColor = True
        ColorFuente1.Visible = True
        Colorfuente2.Visible = False
        If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.ForeColor = cdlg.Color
            reciente2.Text = cdlg.Color.ToString 'I've converted this tostring, so   that recent colors are shown as text, this is what im trying to reverse
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

     If Reciente1.Text = "Ninguno" Then
        MessageBox.Show("No hay colores recientes", "Bloc de notas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else : RichTextBox1.ForeColor = Reciente1.Text 'I get the error here, I have to change this text to a System.Drawing.Color.
    End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `cdlg.Color.ToString` it doesn't really convert it to a string that it can read afterwards. It just convert it to something like *"color [Yellow]"*.

If you want to use `Color.FromName` you will have to pass it just *"Yellow"*, otherwise it will return something unexpected. Probably a color object with a default value o a nothing value.

I'd suggest you to use a `ColorConverter`

```
Dim colorConv As New ColorConverter
TextBox1.Text = colorConv.ConvertToString(cdg.Color)
```

This will return a string "Yellow", that you can use however you like.

```
'Using FormName
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromName(TextBox1.Text)
'Using the color converter again (recommended).
Dim colorConv As New ColorConverter
TextBox1.BackColor = colorConv.ConvertFromString(TextBox1.Text)
```

You can also use substring to get the *"Yellow"* part in *"Color [Yellow]"*. :P

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a Color *object* in order to assign it to `ForeColor`.

The [`Color.FromName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx) method will take a `string` and return a matching `Color` object (assuming it exists):

```
 If Reciente1.Text = "Ninguno" Then
    MessageBox.Show("No hay colores recientes", "Bloc de notas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
Else 
  Dim col As Color = Color.FromName(Reciente1.Text)
  RichTextBox1.ForeColor = col
End If
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you all that answered, but now I have another problem, every time I press "reciente1" the color goes black, instead of the color of the button text. If someone can give me a solution, please.
Thanks to all in advance, again.

Answer (score 1):

Is this WinForms or WPF?

In WinForms, there's a Color.FromName that will convert a know color name back to a color. So you can do something like this:

```
Color.FromName("SlateBlue")
```

In WPF, I believe you can use the ColorConverter class.

Comment: Ok, thanks you all that answered, but now I have another problem, every time I press "reciente1" the color goes black, instead of the color of the button text. If someone can give me a solution, please. Thanks to all in advance, again.

Comment: @minimino: Sounds like a separate question. What's the code for the click handler for "reciente1"? What "goes black"?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the name is proper, and I expect it would be if you're using `ToString`([**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50cb8sdx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) and not messing with it otherwise, yo ucan use the [`Color.FromName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx) method. Although you would have to be careful; if the `reciente` content is editable at all you could be in for some trouble, so naturally, you should *attempt* the conversion back to work, but maybe not *expect* it to.

[**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50cb8sdx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) It is possible for `Color.ToString` to return something *other* than a definite name of the colour:

> '*A string that is the name of this Color, if the Color is created
>   from a predefined color by using either the FromName method or the
>   FromKnownColor method; otherwise, a string that consists of the ARGB
>   component names and their values.'*

Comment: Ok, thanks you all that answered, but now I have another problem, every time I press "reciente1" the color goes black, instead of the color of the button text. If someone can give me a solution, please. Thanks to all in advance, again.